# AngularJS: ng-click function not working with $http.get data

Tags: angularjs, http-get

In the following code, print_label is the function linked to ng-click. All the data from the http-get shows in the document but when I click the button, nothing happens. How can I assign data from an $http.get call?

```
invoice_app.controller('main_ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(root_url + '/dummy_data.php')
           .then(function(res){

              $scope.invoice = res.data;

            $scope.print_label = function($scope) {
                alert($scope.invoice.id);
            }                        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that the data coming back is an array? Because I have it working in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/YIfDNg?p=preview

Comment: It's strange, because if I use the .success(data) function in $http.get it works.

Comment: Ok, I got it. The $scope can't be passed in my print_label function. If I remove that, it also works with .then(). Thanks for posting your code, that helped me find the problem.